# Как в Yii2 заставить работь jQuery и собственный скрипт одновременно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, скрипт

Опытным путем было выяснено, что пока Yii не подгрузит jQuery (а делает он это в последнюю очередь), мой скрипт работать не будет, потому что $ ему в тот момент еще не знаком.

В интернете был вычитан способ исправить ситуацию **вот так:**

```
'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
```

Что, собственно, помогло, но поломало все остальное (в моем случае это многоуровневое меню).

**Далее был испробован другой способ:**

```
$this->registerJs(
'вот тут мой код с js');
```

Что заставило работать меню, но не повлияло на мой скрипт.

Можно было бы вынести скрипт в отдельный файлик и в его настройках указывать подключение в последнюю очередь, однако в моем велосипедном JS используется php и конкатенация (я так переменную туда передаю), поэтому не вижу ничего хорошего в том, чтобы выносить это в отдельный файл.

Как наговнокодить получше и так, чтобы работало и меню и мое чудо-колесо?

**Попробовала также обернуть JS в**

```
jQuery(window).load()
```

На что получила - uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

Код скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var water = <?= $count['full']*250 ?>; //устанавливаем значение переменной, если пользователь уже пил воду в мл.
  $(".off, .on").click(function(){ //меняем класс офф на он
    $(this).toggleClass("off on");
    if($(this).hasClass("on")){
      water += 250; //прибавляем к переменной еще 250 мл.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('site/index') ?>",
        data: "water=" + water,
        _csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
      });
    } if ($(this).hasClass("off")) {
      water -= 250; //если пользователь ошибся и кликнул еще раз на стакан - отнимаем 250 мл.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('site/index') ?>",
        data: "water=" + water,
        _csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
      });
    }
  });
})
```

### **В итоге заработало вот это: (проблема была в используемом методе)**

```
<?php
$count = $count['full']*250;
$url = Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('site/index');

$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){
  var water = $count;
  $(".off, .on").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("off on");
    if($(this).hasClass("on")){
      water += 250;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "$url",
        data: "water=" + water
      });
    } if ($(this).hasClass("off")) {
      water -= 250;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "$url",
        data: "water=" + water
      });
    }
  });
})
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, yii\web\View::POS_END);
?>
```

Comment: а как вы подключаете "чудо-колесо"?

Comment: Стыдно признаться, что никак, прямо во вьюшке внизу в теге <script>. Если бы не мое использование переменной php из этой вьюшки, а также ссылки на action, можно было бы его вынести.
Код скрипта вставлю на всякий случай в вопрос.

Comment: во вьюшке `$this->registerJs()` должно подключать скрипты после всех бандлов, у вас точно с этим методом ничего не вышло?

Comment: попробую еще раз, на всякий

Comment: Все, дошло. READY заменить на END.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в строке _csrf : "$token" есть смысл? Токен вроде как в  data надо передавать. У Вас скорее всего вообще csrf валидация не используется...

Comment: Да, вы правы, смысла и правда нет. Это осталось с предыдущих попыток заставить работать аякс, спасибо за замечание)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге помог все же метод registerJs. Полный код приведен внизу в теле вопроса.

**Замечания, которые пригодились бы мне:**

1. В тех местах, где используются расчеты или вызовы функций php, лучше писать именно переменные, объявленные заранее, иначе будут проблемы с кавычками.
2. Переменные надо использовать без дополнительных символов, а просто сразу вставлять в JS. Мне было не по себе, но оно заработало.
3. Писать метод END, или хотя бы перепробовать все доступные методы

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs()-detail

(а не просто скопировать из интернета, потому что у кого-то сработал именно READY, например).